# How to show both array keys and values?

Tags: php, html

I want to build a dynamically generated Opening Hour List for my website to highlight the current day.

In the first step I want to generate the HTML list via PHP. Unfortunately, this does not work. My code:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        /* Sunday = 0 */
        $daynumber_of_week = date('w', strtotime('Sunday'));

        /* Define Opening Hours */
        $openingHours = array(
            "sunday" => array("Closed"),
            "monday" => array("Closed"),
            "tuesday" => array("8.30 am - 3.00 pm"),
            "wednesday" => array("8.30 am - 1.30 pm", "2.00 pm - 7.00 pm"),
            "thursday" => array("8.30 am - 0.30 pm", "2.00 pm - 7.00 pm"),
            "friday" => array("8.30 am - 0.30 pm", "1.00 pm - 6.00 pm"),
            "saturday" => array("8.30 am - 2.00 pm")
        );

        /* Create Opening Hours */
        for ($x = 0; $x < count($openingHours); $x++)
        {
            echo '<li class="list-unstyled-item d-flex">' . $openingHours[$x] . '<span class="ml-auto">' . $openingHours[$x][0] . '</span></li>';

            if (isset($openingHours[$x][1]))
            {
                echo '<li class="list-unstyled-item d-flex"><span class="ml-auto">' . $openingHours[$x][1] . '</span></li>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

I want to display the following in the echo line, but it shows nothing:

```
$openingHours[$x] -> e.g. wednesday
$openingHours[$x][0] -> first Value of wednesday e.g. "8.30 am - 1.30 pm"
$openingHours[$x][1] -> second Value of wednesday e.g. "2.00 pm - 7.00 pm"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is being made unnecessarily complicated. Use a extended [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

```
$daynumber_of_week = date('w', strtotime('Sunday'));

/* Define Opening Hours */
$openingHours = array(
    "sunday" => array("Closed"),
    "monday" => array("Closed"),
    "tuesday" => array("8.30 am - 3.00 pm"),
    "wednesday" => array("8.30 am - 1.30 pm", "2.00 pm - 7.00 pm"),
    "thursday" => array("8.30 am - 0.30 pm", "2.00 pm - 7.00 pm"),
    "friday" => array("8.30 am - 0.30 pm", "1.00 pm - 6.00 pm"),
    "saturday" => array("8.30 am - 2.00 pm")
);

foreach ($openingHours as $key => $value) {
    echo '<li class="list-unstyled-item d-flex">' . $key . '<span class="ml-auto">' . $value[0] . '</span></li>';

    if (isset($value[1]))
    {
        echo '<li class="list-unstyled-item d-flex"><span class="ml-auto">' . $value[1] . '</span></li>';
    }
}
```

**Note:** In the instance that you are not aware, you can use `[]` to declare an array instead of `array()` as of PHP 5.4.

**Live Example**

[Repl](https://repl.it/repls/FormalTintedSequences)

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gt2a02yx/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$openHoursHtml = '<ul>';

foreach($openingHours as $day => $openHoursArr)
{
    $openHoursHtml .= "<li><span class='day'>" . $day . "</span>";
    $openHoursHtml .= "<span class='hours'>" . implode(",", $openHoursArr) . "</span>";
    $openHoursHtml .= '</li>';
}

$openHoursHtml .= '</ul>';
echo $openHoursHtml;
```

Comment: Good thinking on the `implode` but I think the OP wants to include separate markup for the second key.